# Azure CDN not accepting querystring param for Imageresizer plugin in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, imageresizer, azure-cdn

I have below URL,

https://abc.azureedge.net/stays/img/bg-map1400.jpg?width=500
and its gives image width 500 but this same image calling from azure CDN then is not work

https://abcCDN.azureedge.net/stays/img/bg-map1400.jpg?width=500

its gives me original image only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the caching rule in your CDN profile to 'Cache every unique URL'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-query-string

Comment: did you purge the cache?

Comment: are you taking about "ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache in the NuGet package", No i am not using this plugin.

Comment: No any caching plugin using.

Comment: You are taling about below link caching, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-caching-rules. So i have not setup any caching rule on azure portal

Comment: no, open your endpoint in CDN and click 'Purge' button at the top

Comment: Yes, did this, i am gone my endpoint from cdn and click on purge and open a popup and in content path textbox added /* but still not working.

Comment: which CDN are you using Microsoft, Akamai or Verizon?

Comment: I am using Akamai

Comment: I just deployed a test app with image resizer at https://imageresizersk.azurewebsites.net/ and connected Akamai CDN at https://imageresizersk.azureedge.net/ Just changed  query string caching behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu3X0.png

you can test the plugin at https://imageresizersk.azureedge.net/Images/dancing.jpg?width=200

Comment: I have applied same setting what you have added but still not able to get this result, firstly crated endpoint in CDN  with custom origin and originpath "/abc" and then applied caching rules setting which you have provided, blob image is already provided, so check with URL but resize image is working on website and its not working on CDN.

Comment: container should be public or private?

Comment: Try removing origin path. Also blob accessibility shouldn't be a factor as long as web app can access images in blob

Comment: I need too purchase license version of it? or in free verrsion also its work?

Comment: it's part of pricing. nothing additional is required

Comment: I found some hint of issue.You have point your cdn to blob storage or imageresizer server?

Comment: to imageresizer server

Comment: How to point CDN to image resize server? In my case i have created one CDN profile and into it created endpoint to point that blob storage, so what i need to do create new endpoint? if yes so what should select here in attached image link [https://imgur.com/a/LjvQ9xL](https://imgur.com/a/LjvQ9xL) please let me know what we need to select origin type, origin host name,origin path, origin host header.

Comment: actually you don't need a profile point to blob storage. Just a single CDN profile with an endpoint to your web app. the Origin Hostname would be something like xyz.azurewebsites.net